# This python code that I am running returns nothing but a blank string when I run it

Tags: python

I tried running the sentence... "Can you speak pig latin?"

```
def igpay(sentence):
    alist = sentence.split(" ")
    NewSentence = ""
    vowels = "aeoiu"
    cons = "qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm"
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        c = alist[i]
        if c[0] in vowels:
            a = c + "way"
            NewSentence += a
        elif c[0] not in vowels:
            for j in range(len(c)):
                f = c[j]
                if f in cons:
                    o = c.replace(c[j],"")
                    a = c[j:j+1]
                    b = o + a
                    if f in vowels:
                        v = b + "ay"
                        NewSentence += v
    return(NewSentence)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code. You must precede the code with four spaces minimum for the question to recognize it as code.

Comment: please explain what you code is supposed to do, it is such a mess, it's hard to guess

Comment: Sorry this is my first time but I am trying to translate this sentence into simple pig latin using the two rules...                            1. For any word that begins with one or more consonants (y is considered a consonant): 
move the consonants to the end of the word and append the string 'ay'. 
2. For all other words, append the string 'way' to the end.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're seeing nothing is that neither of the lines with `NewSentence +=` is never reached.

The first line is never reached because there are no words that begin with vowels.

The second line is never reached because your test `if f in vowels` is never executed unless `if f in cons` is already known to be true.  I think you may possibly have an indentation error here.

A few other notes:

- Your two `for` statements could be more clearly written `for word in alist:` and `for ltr in word:` (I used the variable `word` instead of `c` because I think it's clearer).  You do not need to loop on an integer value and then index based on that variable.
- Your outermost  `if/elif` pair can more clearly be written `if/else`.  There's no other possible route of execution.
- Your statements testing `in vowels` or `in cons` will fail for upper-case letters.
- Your replace() call will replace *all* instances of the vowel, not just the first one.  (I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, is it to strip off the initial consonant and place it on the end?)

Comment: Why would it not be reached since they are if statements so if the first letter is not a vowel then it would move on to the elif statement?

Comment: Because Python organizes code blocks by indentation.  If the posted question correctly reflects your code, then everything indented under `if f in cons:` will *only* be executed if that condition is true.

Comment: The code loops over alist and c, but I don't see either of those values changed inside the loops, unless I'm missing something obvious.  I don't think that's a problem.